# Overdispersion Mixed generalized linear model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I am running a mixed generalized linear model to analyze insect capture in a baited trap. The experiment consisted of 3 separate cages, in each one one treatment (C+, C- or T) and 10 insects were placed. The next day the number of insects captured in each treatment was counted. I have an experimental series in which there are 5 replicates (nights) per treatment. My model is mod1 <- glmer(Capture/total ~ Treatment + (1 | Trial), family = binomial, weights = total, data = data1). When checking the assumptions I obtain a dispersion of 5.42, (dispersion <- sum(res^2) / df). I tried running a quasi-Poisson model and the dispersion dropped to 0.7, but I find it difficult to interpret the results with this model. I have another experimental series with 8 replicates and a dispersion value of 1.6. In this case, how much importance should I give to that value to discard the model with binomial distribution? For both series, considering the overdispersion, is it correct to use quasi-poisson for this type of analysis? Should I use a negative binomial model? Is there a way to compare models with different distribution families to know which one fits best? I understand that ANOVA is only to compare models with the same family. I appreciate the response.